# GCC cannot handle function which return reference

Tags: gcc, reference

I have a strange error. I'm trying to compile my program as at bottom in gcc. In g++ it compiles without errors, but in GCC I get: `error: expected identifier or '(' before '&' token`
 message in line with myFunction declaration.

Do you know if I can return reference in C language?

My module.h file:

```
//module.h
const int& myFunction();
```

My module.cpp file:

```
//module.c
const unsigned long& myFunction()
{
  static int x = 123;
  return x;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the exact issue, but isn't it a problem that your function signatures don't match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You talk about `gcc` vs. `g++`, but you also talk about `module.cpp`... are you trying to compile your code as C?

C doesn't have references.

Comment: And if you still have to go about it in this manner you could do what c++ does for you and use a pointer.